# How to set correctly the line height of UILabel with an AttributedString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I have a `UILabel` which uses an Attributed String. I want to have its line height to be exactly the size of the font size, not a pixel bigger. However, a top and bottom padding are being added. See image below:

[image]

This is my code to create the label.

```
NSDictionary *basicAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor], NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blueColor]};

NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:basicAttributes];

UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Regular" size:20.0];
[attributes setObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1.0f;
[attributes setObject:paragraphStyle forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];

self.helloWorldLabel.attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hola" attributes:attributes];
```

### Attempts

I have tried to call `sizeToFit` after setting the attributedText without success.

```
[self.helloWorldLabel sizeToFit];
```

I have played with other attributes of `NSMutableParagraphStyle` such as `lineSpacing` without success.

```
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 0.0f;
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Try changing your text to include letters that go lower, like "y". I think sizeToFit accounts for the highest and lowest letters in the font.

Comment: You are correct crimsonChris. If I enter an y it touches the bottom border. What about the space in the top?

Comment: The link shared by @GeorgePetrov describes why there is space on the top as well.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use `boundingRectWithSize:`  Here's a short example of how to use it.  This code will dynamically determine your label size based on the text in your label.  Setting the constraining sizes allows a max size if content needs to overflow to multiple lines.

```
    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title Header:%@", value];
    NSRange boldRange = [text rangeOfString:@"Title Header:"];
    NSRange normalRange = [text rangeOfString:value];
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];

    //Add attributes for appropriate ranges
    [attributedText setAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:13.0f]} range:boldRange];
    [attributedText setAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13.0f]} range:normalRange];

    //Determine rect for attributed text constrained within max values
    CGRect textAttributedSize = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CellTitleWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context:NULL];
   [self.myLabel setText:attributedText]; 
   [self.myLabel setFrame:textAttributedSize];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [**link**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Font_metrics). There is no 100% way to correctly set the frame to fit the letters. You can calculate the attributed string with `CoreText` like using `CTFramesetterRef` `CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints` but it is more additional work.